# Слушатель на касание экрана

Tags: android

Есть идея экономить батарейку, и усыплять некоторые процессы если пользователь долго не трогает экран.
Как можно отловить событие на касание экрана?
У меня есть куча view  на экране, так же есть отдельные фрагменты. И на каждый элемент не хочется вешать OnClickListener.
Есть же более гуманный способ, возможно ловить запрос от сенсора?
Буду рад любым идеям.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Создайте свой вариант корневого `Activity`, в котором все касания "ловятся", типа:

```
public class MyRootActivity extends Activity {
   //blah-blah

   @Override
   void onUserInteraction() {
      super.onUserInteraction();
      //далее ваш код слушателя
   }

}
```

Теперь, если все ваши `Activity` будут унаследованы от этой, то при касании любого элемента будет срабатывать `onUserInteraction()` - остальное уже дело техники.

Comment: Все работает, спасибо большое